# What's the single word that represents the act of accusing other of stating the obvious (though that's not true)

Tags: single-word-requests

**Situation 1:**

A tells B that an old relative passed away.

```
B doesn't have prior knowledge of this
```

B says, > he is an old man...

(or something like that which implies that she is not surprised because old people die one day) - faulty logic, granted!

**Situation 2:**

A and B are sitting in a porch having a casual conversation

A: > It is unusually hot today, isn't it?

B: > Yeah, it is peak summer

What is one word that describes B's attitude of saying what others informed her is obvious and unsurprising though she (B) has no prior knowledge about it.

Comment: The single word for accusing someone of stating the obvious is, “***Duh!***” (said with as much sarcasm as can be mustered.)

Comment: Although it may be obvious, "obviously" is also used as a one word response in the situations you describe.

Comment: @Jim the question is what do you call someone who "duh!" everything even when there's no duh in what's stated. :D

Comment: @Zan700 fortunately my English is not that bad...I don't need to ask if the answer to my question is the word "obviously"...or its adjective cousin. please read the question again.

Comment: @Pura - So you aren’t asking for a word that represents the act of accusing someone of stating the obvious? You are instead asking what do you call someone who always states the obvious?

Comment: Some people might say “Yeah B is a real “master of the obvious”...”   Not one word however.  ;-)

Comment: @Pura Well, if you're seeking a general attitude, blasé might work. Blase: "unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before."

Comment: @Zan700 dang! that's very close...thank you! I think the rest of the attitude is close to a logical fallacy 'begging the question' - not sure though.

I said 'very close' because the person in question hasn't experienced or seen/done it before but pretends to have. Perhaps this complex attitude too rare to warrant a term/word.

Comment: @Pura Good. I'm going to post it as an answer if only to see how quickly someone will then vote to close the question.

Comment: @Zan700 - I'm new here and don't have enough reputations to vote. :|

Comment: B is a know-it-all, and tries to feign knowledge.  A dismisses B's comments.  A is dismissive.

Comment: @aparente001 haha, that's a simple and an interesting take. Where do we go from here?

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean what's the next step in stackexchange terms, in dealing with your question?  Or do you mean, how do you deal with someone who is dismissive?  Or something else?

Comment: @aparente001 I meant the later...but on second thought, I'd let it rest. The question is only meant to find a suitable word. Thank you.

Comment: Some psychologists recommend using "I statements." For ex: "I feel like my point of view is not being taken into account." Personally, what I try to do is, first, recap what the other person is saying, and say something insightful about the other person's feelings, and then ask him/her: "Do you understand my point of view?" If the answer is a dry "Yes," then: "Okay, can you recap my point of view? I want to see if I've been explaining myself clearly." In interpersonal relationships, the word for something is not always as important as being aware of how you feel and what you want. (My 2 cents)

Answer (score 0):

if you're seeking a general attitude, blasé might work. Blase: "unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before." Oxford Online.